# React router v4 role base authorization

Tags: react-router-v4, role-base-authorization

I am new to react world and added router v4 but not able to implement react role base authorization. Let me know if any source which make me go to proper way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [react-router-role-authorization](https://github.com/burczu/react-router-role-authorization) (the approach described in [Role-based authorization using React-Router](http://frontendinsights.com/role-based-authorization-using-react-router/)) and [redux-auth-wrapper](https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper).

Comment: I have checked all those options but they are in an older version of the router. I am grateful that you reply to this post. I look for version 4.

Comment: redux-auth-wrapper should work fine with Router v4:

https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper/tree/master/examples/react-router-4